# Onclick attribute with multiple function

Tags: javascript

Is there any way i can call three function which takes input as a parameter and return nothing? I don't want to use click event of jquery i am looking to pass three function in attribute level.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  Show that you have done some of your own research and you should get more helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more specific answer, please ask a more specific question. The following answer is valid for

> Is there any way i can call three function which takes input as a
>   parameter and return nothing? I don't want to use click event of
>   jquery i am looking to pass three function in attribute level.

```
<button onclick="first(1);second(2);third(3);">go</button>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I want to call all this three function on dt tag. Your answer is working on button tag. But how about dt tag?